# How to remove "jumps" of trackpoints in Camera tracking when moving them?

Tags: camera, tracking

Since I moved my trackpoints I got this jumps where the line of a trackpoint jumps from the red to the green curve(and the other way around).
This happened to points that I moved, so maybe that's the reason. Is there a simple solution, or do I have to replace all these trackpoints?
[image: *screenshot*]

Comment: see http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14330/motion-tracking-what-do-the-graphs-represent-and-how-are-they-useful

Comment: @Backfighter Rather than editing your question post an answer to the question, explaining how you solved the problem.

Comment: Isn't possible only after 5 hours ^^

Answer (score 1):

> see [blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14330/…](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14330/motion-tracking-what-do-the-graphs-represent-and-how-are-they-useful) –  cegaton 56 mins ago

So my answer is solved now I think. After reading this I know, that the "jumps" the lines are doing are caused by moving them. Because if you move one its speed increases immensely. And if the lines indicate the speed of a tracker, they will go up too. That's causing the jumps.

The other points where the red and the green line is connected. A new Trackpoint was created.

Answer (score -1):

You need to track those markers again, and then resolve the camera motion. To do this, go to the "Motion Tracking" prespective, by chosing it from this menu:
[image]

Then select the markers that need to be tracked, open the Toolshelf (press <kbd>T</kbd>) and go to the subsection "Track" and click the track button, as shown here:

[image]:

Comment: Please add some more details, such as steps on how to achieve what you have suggested.

Comment: He already did this, since he has that graph, but fine....

Comment: So the only possibility is to track them again?
I see lot of work coming towards me :s :D
And yes someonewithpc is right ^^

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think so...