# Tracking and solve error

Tags: tracking

Im tracking a scene, and have 14 points tracked with a solve error of 1.16 im trying to get this below one. I have found a point with a solve error of over 2 so i tryed deleting this to see the effect on the overall solve error and blender doesn't like it saying "some data failed to reconstuct" does any one know why this is?

Comment: Also read the following links: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42329/camera-tracking-problem and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14330/motion-tracking-what-do-the-graphs-represent-and-how-are-they-useful