# Motion Tracking in the woods

Tags: motion-capture

I shot with some friends a star wars shot in the woods. We want to make a scene, where everything stands still (frozen time effect) and a blaster-shot hangs in the air. For that we need to motion track it in blender. But It is very hard because the camera is moving very strongly. Many keyframes have already lost their path after some frames. I have to tick the trip box in the motion editor (solve panle) that I can even track my scene. I get a solving error of about 26 and that's not even quite good. Can anyone help me please! I don't know how to fix it and get the track at least a little bit better. I would love to get some tips from you because we can't shoot the scene again. As you can see I'm not the best in Motion-tracking and still a beginner so if it is possible, don't make it too complicated and give me a good explanation. Thank you for the help! :)

The woods looks like this:[image]

Comment: You should start by watching **Track, Match, Blend 2"** by Sebastian Koening. (https://www.google.com/search?q=track+match+blend+2&oq=track+match+b&aqs=chrome.2.0j69i57j0l4.8139j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: You should aim to have a solve error of 0.3.  An error of 26 pixels is way too high.  Also, the way you solve the shot will depend on the kind of motion (if the camera is being displaced or if it is just rotating on an axis). Fast motion, blurry images, low contrast and areas with that don't have clearly distinct features are the most complicated to track and solve. If you are a beginner know in advance that motion tracking is complex, and you need a good understanding of the tools, to pull off  a decent camera reconstruction.

Comment: Thank you for the help already! Do I have to use for example only perspective keyframes or can I also mix them ?

Comment: And what is the blue line in the move clip editor ?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14330/motion-tracking-what-do-the-graphs-represent-and-how-are-they-useful