# My object is sliding in video after rendering

Tags: tracking

So I have been trying to learn how to do motion tracking and I have a good solve error of 0.5507. I thought that after I rendered my object in my video wouldn't experience any irrational moving or sliding but I was wrong. I don't know what I'm doing wrong...

[Here is the video so you guys can see whats going on.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9QbdOAT7Nd4)

[image]

Is it these spikes in my graph that is causing it to slide around? I've read that deleting these spikes will get rid of the sliding, but literally all of my tracks do this so deleting the spike would mean deleting all my tracks. 
[image]

anyone know how to fix this?

Also here are the files so you can take a look at it all yourself.

[The Files](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/rfd1b6qv7rvd9pc/AABGSBCS1v3SHS_eb6dy1WdWa?dl=0)

Comment: Wait nvm... I think I know what's going on. When I scrub through my video and go over those spikes, I can see in the track preview that the points kinda lose their spot. [See here](https://gph.is/2K7Gez5)

Comment: read https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14330/motion-tracking-what-do-the-graphs-represent-and-how-are-they-useful