# how to view selected keyframes in clip graph editor

Tags: movie-clip-editor

I'm doing motion tracking in blender and having problem to view selected keyframes. Is there any way i can do 'view selected' the selected keyframes in clip graph editor ? Am i missing something here ? or this basic feature just doesn't exist in clip graph editor ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graphs on the Movie Clip Editor are quite different than most other parts of the interface, even tough they look similar. Think of them informational instead of editing tools.

To view a particular tracker it helps to open the Track section in the numeric panel on the right of the screen.

[image]

That will show you the search box for that particular tracker at the current frame. The tracker can be selected directly on the Clip editor window.

But can also be selected by clicking on the dopesheet or on a particular line in the graph.

[image]

But unfortunately there  is no way to make the cursor jump to a specific keyframe. In the Dope Sheet keyframes are not selectable.

In the Graph window you can select the point for a specific frame, but the normal keyboard shortcut to make the cursor jump to that frame does not work.

The only way to bring the cursor to a specific point is by manually placing the cursor on that specific frame.

[image]

**Further reading:**

[Motion Tracking. What do the graphs represent and how are they useful?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14330/motion-tracking-what-do-the-graphs-represent-and-how-are-they-useful)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of what you are refering to "view selected".

Do you mean to only display the curves of selected components ?
If so, push down the little arrov button in the graph editor's header :
[image: arrow button]

Do you mean to focus the view on your selection ? Simply hit the <kbd>numpad .</kbd> (dot) key.

Comment: i mean those numpad . (view selection). But this hotkey won't work in clip graph editor because in the 'view' menu , there's no 'view selection' actually. I can only see view all. Also in preference, if i go to clip graph editor, there's no view selection , there's no way i can set the hotkey.

Comment: Just to clarify things... Which editor are you talking about ? There are no "clip graph editor", but there's a "graph editor" and a "clip editor". Both have a "view selected" command, which is also mappend on numpad .

Comment: it's because inconsistency in blender 2.8.  in UI, change the panel to 'movie clip editor' and set it to 'graph' , just exactly the same as your screenshot. But  in Preferences go to  keymap/clip/clip graph editor. In the pref it's called 'clip graph editor'. There, i can't set hotkey for 'view selection'.

Comment: Oh well, in that case we are talking about the "Movide Clip Editor in graph view". And I'm affraid there are no operator available for zooming on the selected keys. Actually there are a lot of things missing. Which is... At least weird. Maybe it's possible to kind of bring it through a python script, but I can't help on that. I guess it would be nice to report it on blender.community/c/rightclickselect  or devtalk.blender.org