# Camera motion tracking: How to adjust to make the solve < 0.5?

Tags: camera, tracking

I am trying to understand how to best approach adjusting a camera track to get the error down to something < 0.5 px

- Video clip is 141 frames, HD
- There are 8 markers/tracks
- All of these tracks look good when I visually inspect them

The solve gives me 2.48 px and the the graph, tells me that some of the tracks have errors around 3-5. I can't visually see why it is so:

[image]

If I select one of the tracks, "Track.001":

[image]

and follow that during the 141 frames, I dont see why it is so bad, see this video:

http://somup.com/cYlt1L27xM

The "quick view", in the top right, its just a "mush", not clear at all, so it is hard to use, but from what I can tell, the track is on point.

If someone is interested in helping a newbie out, I can upload the PNG files (248 MB) and the project file.

---- EDIT ----

After adding about 4 more tracks, the error goes up to 169.09 px. When testing different "Refine" options, no change. The weirdest thing is that I can see the "per frame average error" (blue line below), but when looking for a blue line per track, there is none:

[image]

Comment: Ensure your solver Lens settings are set appropriate to the device you have recorded your footage with. It’s important that it matches as closely as possible. There are presets for common camera devices (eg, iPhone) and this can make a big difference in the accuracy of the camera solve.

Comment: Read also [motion tracking, What do the graphs represent and how are they useful](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14330/motion-tracking-what-do-the-graphs-represent-and-how-are-they-useful)

Comment: The camera is not being displaced, but is just rotating. There is no parallax information that way. You will not get a 3D reconstruction out of that shot. You can only solve a shot like that with tripod solve. Also the checkered pattern on the floor might make the tracking jump, as there are not enough uinique elements to track.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I actually tried the "tripod" solve, and that made it much much worse, even though my initial thought would be "tripod", as I wasnt moving much, just panning, more or less. Also had a hard time figuring out the Huawei P30 lens, but I finally set 16 mm (sensor) and 17 mm (focal length). No idea if that helped of made things worse.